# Safran 2S2 Engine Overhaul

Tags: engine, turbine

Does overhaul of Safran 2S2 Engine reset all engine inspections? If engine TSO is 0 as of today, does it mean I can reset all 15/20/30/300/600/3000/3500 hours inspection to be 0?

Or I have to see Shop Visit report to see what work has been performed while overhaul?
My understanding is, we can't make all engine inspections 0, but, we have to see Shop Visit report to see what tasks they have performed on overhaul.

Thanks,

Comment: Under what aviation authority do you operate?

Comment: FAA, I would like to know how does it matter?